# Char pointer to pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to have an array of strings where in each index of this array exists another array of strings.

```
char Example[0] = { "array", "of", "strings"}
Example[1] = { "array", "of", "strings2"}
Example[...] = { ... }
```

I have thought of trying to use char **array[some_number] as a way to do this, but I have found the syntax to be uncomfortable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    char *test[10] = {0};
    char *ex[3] = {0};

    ex[0] = "array";
    ex[1] = "of";
    ex[2] = "strings";

    test[3] = *ex;

    printf("Content of test[3] = %s %s\n", test[3], ???);

    return 0;
}
```

I am having difficulty trying to print this out... is there any other way I can go about achieving what I have mentioned? Any resources/help would be great.

Comment: It *almost* sounds like you're trying to manufacture an array of array of pointer to const string. I use "almost" there because I read your post four times and I still couldn't discern what you seek for sure.

Comment: `char *Example[][3] = {{ "array", "of", "strings"}, { "array", "of", "strings2"}, /*...*/};` ?

Comment: Well, what I am really trying to do is create a hash table of virtual memory addresses. My initial thought is that using some type of hash I group specific addresses into "buckets." I thought that if I had an array of pointers to arrays that I could achieve this. I got lost in the syntax though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure about exactly what you want, but if you want an array containing pointers to arrays of strings, then you have two alternatives.

The first is to remember that arrays decays to a pointer to its first element. For an array of strings like

```
const char *array_of_strings[3] = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
```

then the result of the decay (which is equal to `&array_of_strings[0]`) is a pointer to a pointer to a `const char`, i.e. `const char**`. That means to have an array of that, you make something like

```
const char **array_or_arrays_1[] = { array_of_strings };
```

The other way is to have a pointer to an explicit array of strings, using the address of operator `&`. When you to `&array_of_strings` you get a pointer to an array of three pointers to `char`, the type is `const char *(*)[3]`. You can declare it easily using type-aliases:

```
typedef const char *(array_of_3_strings_t)[3];
array_of_3_strings *array_of_arrays_2[] = { &array_of_strings };
```

Comment: How can I make this more dynamic?

Comment: @JeffGreene Type-aliases (using `typedef`) and `malloc`?

Comment: @JeffGreene What exactly do you mean by more "*dynamic*"?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const char* example[] = { "array", "of", "strings" };
```

That's an array of 3 (implicitly) pointers to arrays of char which cannot be modified.  Read the first one by `example[0]`.

Comment: I'm gonna need a more dynamic approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand what are you saying about "more dynamic approach".
Maybe you want to make array of list, which each list (of string) can has different size. If that was you want, this codes may help:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef char * string;
int main()
{
    string array1[]={"apple","durian"};
    string array2[]={"mustard","carrot","spinach"};
    string array3[]={"garlic","onion","pepper", "blackpepper"};

    string
        * array_of_array[]={ array1,
                             array2,
                             array3 };


    printf("\n%s %s", array_of_array[0][1],array_of_array[2][3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Console Result:

> durian blackpepper

But, if you mean all resource must be initialized dynamically, so this code may help...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef char * string;
typedef string * arrayString;
typedef arrayString * arrayList;

string newString(char * temp);
arrayString newArrayString(int size);
arrayList newArrayList(int size);

int main()
{
//Example 1, static allocation, string constant
    string array1[]={"apple","durian"};
    string array2[]={"mustard","carrot","spinach"};
    string array3[]={"garlic","onion","pepper", "blackpepper"};

    arrayString Example_One[3]={ array1, array2, array3 };

//Example 2, dynamic allocation using pointer struct
/************************************************************/
    arrayList Example_Two=newArrayList(3);
        arrayString ExTwoValue1=newArrayString(2);
        arrayString ExTwoValue2=newArrayString(3);
        arrayString ExTwoValue3=newArrayString(4);

        Example_Two[0]=ExTwoValue1;
            ExTwoValue1[0]=newString("apple2");
            ExTwoValue1[1]=newString("durian2");
        Example_Two[1]=ExTwoValue2;
            ExTwoValue2[0]=newString("mustard2");
            ExTwoValue2[1]=newString("carrot2");
            ExTwoValue2[2]=newString("spinach2");
        Example_Two[2]=ExTwoValue3;
            ExTwoValue3[0]=newString("garlic2");
            ExTwoValue3[1]=newString("onion2");
            ExTwoValue3[2]=newString("pepper2");
            ExTwoValue3[3]=newString("blackpepper2");
            
/************************************************************/
            
//Print Result Here...      
    printf("\n%s %s", Example_One[0][0],Example_One[2][3]);
    printf("\n\n%s %s", Example_Two[0][0],Example_Two[2][3]);

    return 0;
}

string newString(char * temp)
{
    string str =  (string)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp)+2));
    strcpy(str,temp);
    return str;
}

arrayString newArrayString(int size)
{
    arrayString arrStr= (arrayString)malloc(sizeof(string)*size);
    return arrStr;
}

arrayList newArrayList(int size)
{
    arrayList arrLst= (arrayList)malloc(sizeof(arrayString)*size);
    return arrLst;
}
```

Console Result:

> apple blackpepper
>
> apple2 blackpepper2